# NHibernate SessionFactory handled by .NET Core DI

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-core

Trying to make the NHibernate SessionFactory as a singleton and Session as scoped, all this handled by the .NET Core dependency injection. I configured those in the Startup.cs as such:

```
services.AddSingleton<NHibernate.ISessionFactory>(factory =>
{
    return Fluently
                .Configure()
                .Database(() =>
                {

                    return FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration
                            .MsSql2012
                            .ShowSql()
                            .ConnectionString(ConnectionString);
                })
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Model>())
                .BuildSessionFactory();
}); 

services.AddScoped<NHibernate.ISession>(factory =>
   factory
        .GetServices<NHibernate.ISessionFactory>()
        .First()
        .OpenSession()
);
```

My question is - how do I exactly pass the Session or the SessionFactory instance, for instance, in a repository class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just pass the ISession object as a parameter to the repository constructor.

```
public class Repository {
    private readonly ISession session;

    public Repository(NHibernate.ISession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public void DoSomething() {
        this.session.SaveOrUpdate(...);
    }
}
```

When you ask for a Repository-instance from the ServicesCollection (DI), the ISession will be resolved automatically.