# nFluent NHibernate .net Core sessionmanagement

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am a java developer new to Dotnet and trying to build a application using .net core 2.2 and nHibernate 5.2. But not sure how to do session management properly.

In Java Spring we use to use @Transactional annotation and things were already taken care, but not able to see similar things here or might be i am not doing configuration correctly

I used the help of below url 
[NHibernate SessionFactory handled by .NET Core DI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47742926/nhibernate-sessionfactory-handled-by-net-core-di)
but doesn't provide much details.
it gives me error cannot use scoped inside singleton which is correct.

This is the layer structure i have 
  Controller --> Service invokes 
                   ( Repository 1,Repository 2 )

So my transaction should start from service layer and all the underline Repository calls should be part of same transaction.
my Startup.cs looks like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        services.AddSingleton<GenericService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IGenericRepository, GenericRepositoryImpl>();


        services.AddSingleton<INHibernateHelper, NHibernateHelper>();


        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSession();
    }
```

And 
NHibernateHelper looks like this

```
public class NHibernateHelper : INHibernateHelper
            {
                private readonly string _connectionString;
                private readonly object _lockObject = new object();
                private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

                public NHibernateHelper(IConfiguration configuration)
                {
                    _connectionString = configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
                }

                private ISessionFactory SessionFactory
                {
                    get
                    {
                        if (_sessionFactory == null)
                        {
                            CreateSessionFactory();
                        }

                        return _sessionFactory;
                    }
                }

                public ISession OpenSession()
                {
                    return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
                }

                private void CreateSessionFactory()
                {

                        var fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure()
                            .Database(
                                MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(_connectionString).ShowSql()
                            )
                            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<GenricEntityMapping>()
                            );

                        _sessionFactory = fluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();

                }
            }
```

I am injecting the Hibernate helper at RepositoryLevel so i can access ISession at Repository level , but every time i have to use

```
using (var session = OpenSession())
{
}
```

How to use this session starting from service layer and same session should propagate to repository level.
If anyone can share (.net and nHibernate) sample working code with service and repository code with transaction at service layer will be highly appreciated

Comment: You need to look at UnitOfWork approach for this. [This](https://nhibernate.info/doc/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern) one explains UnitOfWork with NHibernate

Comment: [One More](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/01/28/unit-of-work-repository-pattern-in-mvc5-and-web-api-2-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-ninject)

Comment: can't we do using nHibernate ISession , that is also UOW , how to implement this in service layer and propagate to repository layer.